# Share current location first device

Tags: android, hypertrack

I  have a question. How I can share location of second device to the first device where hypertrack-live-location-view is installed?It's not clear to me. It's only for viewing. No sharing of second device location is mentioned. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You need to integrate a HyperTrack SDK in your app that will be installed on the **second device**. After integration, you need to create an [Action](https://www.hypertrack.com/actions)(Hypertrack Entity) in the second device so that other devices or users can track.

1. Follow this [guide](https://docs.hypertrack.com/sdks/android/setup.html) to integrate HyperTrack SDK into your android app in second device.
2. Call `HyperTrack.startTracking();`
3. Create [Action](https://www.hypertrack.com/actions) using HyperTrack SDK method `HyperTrack.createAndAssignAction(actionParams, new HyperTrackCallback());`

   Refer [here](https://docs.hypertrack.com/sdks/android/actions.html) for more detail on `HyperTrack.createAndAssignAction` method.
4. Get `actionId` from `action.getId`.
5. Use above `actionId` and pass it to `HyperTrack.trackAction(actionID, new HyperTrackCallback())` in your **first device** in which you have setup live-tracking-view. Refer [here](https://docs.hypertrack.com/usecases/livetracking/android/installing.html) for more detail on live tracking view.

You can connect with us on [hypertrack-slack](http://slack.hypertrack.io/) support channel for any further query.